# Android BLE Devices, Location Permission and New Google Play Family Policy

Tags: android

Im currently working on an application for children which uses BLE fitbands to interact with the app.
I have had this app for 2 years now in the store without major problems.

Thing is, with the new Designed for Families policy I must set the target ages for my app which is under 13. I totally understand the reasoning behind Googles decision on removing this permission for that user age target.

My question is, is my app finished?
Since the entire purpose of the app is motivating children to use fitbands, if I take that permission out I wont be able to use the BLE devices and so I should take the feature out of the app which means the whole business model is reduced to nothing.

Which options do I have?